# Connection Refused on Mac via FTP

Tags: macos, ftp

I have MAC OSX 10.9.5 and I'm new to FTP connection on Mac. I couldn't find a clear list of reasons that I cannot connect to a server. The server is running but when I try to connect through FileZilla, command line ftp, or finder ftp I get an error that says 'Connection Refused'. I didn't get this error a few days ago when I tried to connect so what could have been changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connection refused is frequently when the server does not have the ftp service running. Maybe the daemon is not running anymore? (The server may be running, but maybe just not the FTP service).

Another possibility is that the server's firewall is now blocking the FTP ports. Did anything change there?

Is your username and password correctly programmed?

Yet another possibility is that the data port is blocked by the firewall (FTP uses two ports)

Here are some tests you can run: http://kb.siteground.com/ftp_port_21/

You can also test your ftp server remotely: https://ftptest.net/
(to check if the problem is local or not)

Do a test with:   telnet url 21
You should get a prompt, where you can log in with user xxx and pass xxx
If that works, maybe you have deprogrammed those data in your client.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to make an ftp connection, passive and active. If there is an option for this in your ftp client try toggling it to the other setting and try connecting again. It should be set to Passive for most situations.

[Cyberduck](http://cyberduck.io/) is an excellent ftp client for OS X, I recommend you try it.